# Find processor usage on host machine from within virtual machine?

Tags: linux, vps

I have a Linux VPS, but recently it's been running slow.  Every time I contact the provider, they work on it for 2-3 days, the service seems to speed up (looks like a reboot occurred), but then after about a week the service is bogged down again.

I know I can use programs like `top` to view the information on the system usage from within my walled garden, but is it possible to view the host information from within there as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule, no. Unless you know what virtualization is in use, and that platform supports passing said information through the hypervisor via a special utility. Most virtualization enforces a fairly firm "none of your business" stance on seeing the physical hardware state.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

One hint you *might* get, depending on various kernel versions and options is the `%st` figure from `top` as a percentage (or `vmstat -s` or `/proc/stat` as a cumulative counter). This keeps track of the CPU "stolen" in a guest (so that CPU stats add up).

Comment: So, would this be what my personal guest is utilizing?

Comment: @Kruug No, it's CPU that the guest is _not_ being given, usually because it's reached some limit, or possibly because the VM host is over-committed. This has a reasonably coherent discussion, though it may not be fully applicable to your situation: http://www.axibase.com/cloud/2010/07/22/ec2-monitoring-the-case-of-stolen-cpu/